# SQL Formatting from nvarchar length of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, nvarchar

I have a column in my data set called `Duration` that calculates the length of time the event happened. The current format is in an odd `nvarchar(2000)` format that produces cells like this:

```
7H35M49S (as in 7 hours, 35 minutes, 49 seconds)
32M10S
2H23S
```

(number of hours, numbers of minutes, number of seconds)

How could this be formatted as a total number of seconds?

Some ideas were to use `CHARINDEX` or a substring but I couldn't get it to work.

Thanks for all your help!

Edit: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 17

Comment: which sql database?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 17

Comment: This smells like homework.  Have you tried something yet?  By the way, storing time in this format is an all around really bad idea.

Comment: Sql Server Management Studio **is not a database**.  It's a tool for connecting to databases, and it can be made to connect to most any version of Sql Server. And version is important, because there are some different tools available for this in more recent versions of Sql Server.

Answer (score 1):

Only to solve your issue 
 Below is how I dissected your format and apply basic arithmetic to get the seconds.

```
declare @mytime varchar(100) = '7H35M49S'

select
    isnull(NULLIF(left(@mytime, IIF(charindex('H',@mytime)=0,0,charindex('H',@mytime)-1)),''),0) -- to get Hours
 ,isnull(NULLIF(replace(left(replace(@mytime,left(@mytime, IIF(charindex('H',@mytime)=0,0,charindex('H',@mytime))),''),charindex('M',replace(@mytime,left(@mytime, IIF(charindex('H',@mytime)=0,0,charindex('H',@mytime))),''))),'M',''),''),0) -- to get M
 ,isnull(nullif(
  left(replace(replace(@mytime,left(@mytime, IIF(charindex('H',@mytime)=0,0,charindex('H',@mytime))),''), left(replace(@mytime,left(@mytime, IIF(charindex('H',@mytime)=0,0,charindex('H',@mytime))),''), IIF(charindex('M',replace(@mytime,left(@mytime, IIF(charindex('H',@mytime)=0,0,charindex('H',@mytime))),''))=0,0,charindex('M',replace(@mytime,left(@mytime, IIF(charindex('H',@mytime)=0,0,charindex('H',@mytime))),''))) ),'')
   ,iif(charindex('S',
   replace(replace(@mytime,left(@mytime, IIF(charindex('H',@mytime)=0,0,charindex('H',@mytime))),''), left(replace(@mytime,left(@mytime, IIF(charindex('H',@mytime)=0,0,charindex('H',@mytime))),''), IIF(charindex('M',replace(@mytime,left(@mytime, IIF(charindex('H',@mytime)=0,0,charindex('H',@mytime))),''))=0,0,charindex('M',replace(@mytime,left(@mytime, IIF(charindex('H',@mytime)=0,0,charindex('H',@mytime))),''))) ),'')
   ) = 0,0, 
   charindex('S',
   replace(replace(@mytime,left(@mytime, IIF(charindex('H',@mytime)=0,0,charindex('H',@mytime))),''), left(replace(@mytime,left(@mytime, IIF(charindex('H',@mytime)=0,0,charindex('H',@mytime))),''), IIF(charindex('M',replace(@mytime,left(@mytime, IIF(charindex('H',@mytime)=0,0,charindex('H',@mytime))),''))=0,0,charindex('M',replace(@mytime,left(@mytime, IIF(charindex('H',@mytime)=0,0,charindex('H',@mytime))),''))) ),'')
   )-1)
   )
  ,'')
  ,0)  -- to get S
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Your query fails for certain test cases, [see here](http://rextester.com/VIKK25965).

Comment: what do you mean tim? i know for a fact that this is not the optimum

Comment: Just fix the demo and you should be fine.

Comment: here you go! please test this

Comment: Upvoted.  I could sense that this was going to be a really nasty, ugly query, so I decided not to answer :-)

Comment: true that @TimBiegeleisen. thanks for the upvote and demo link. i almost lost my mind haha